# Where is the source of XNA lighting?

Tags: xna

Talking BasicEffects,
where is the source of the three directional lights?

When I write this:

```
effect.DirectionalLight0.DiffuseColor = new Vector3(0.5f, 0, 0); // a red light
effect.DirectionalLight0.Direction = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
```

What does it mean for the direction? From where is it directing?

Answer (score 4):

Directional lights have no position. Think of the sun lighting objects on earth. Technically it has a position, but it is so far away that it does not matter.

Therefore a directional light will illuminate based only on the angle between the light's direction and the surface normal.

If you want lights with a position that also have attenuation, you want to use point lights.